# Visual Basic error does not add properly

Tags: vb.net-2010

My code for this program is supposed to add the Variable Entries by +1 when the if function is true however when exporting from the message box it adds 1 and then never changes I tried adding a temp variable and it still didn't work. Problem occurs in the first 3 if functions.

```
'Application Name:      Winter Wonderland Donations
```

'Developer:             Jordan Frahmann
'Date:                  1/20/15
'Purpose:               This application is used to calculate the total donations
'                       for ten donations.
Public Class frmWinterWonderlandDonations

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    'This button calculates the donations.
    Dim decDonation2 As Decimal = 2
    Dim decDonation5 As Decimal = 5
    Dim decDonation10 As Decimal = 10
    Dim Entries As Integer = 0
    Dim Donations As Decimal
    Dim TotalDonation As Decimal
    Dim Temp As Decimal



    For Entries = 0 To 10
        If rad2.Checked = True Then
            Donations = decDonation2
            TotalDonation += Donations
            Entries += 1
            lstNumberOfDonations.Items.Add("Donation " & Entries & Donations & txtName.Text & TotalDonation)
            rad2.Checked = False
            MsgBox(Entries)
        ElseIf rad5.Checked = True Then
            Donations = decDonation5
            TotalDonation += Donations
            Entries = Temp
            Entries = Temp + 1
            lstNumberOfDonations.Items.Add("Donation " & Entries & Donations & txtName.Text & TotalDonation)
            rad5.Checked = False
        ElseIf rad10.Checked = True Then
            Donations = decDonation10
            TotalDonation += Donations
            Entries = Entries + 1
            lstNumberOfDonations.Items.Add("Donation " & Entries & Donations & txtName.Text & TotalDonation)
            rad10.Checked = False
        End If

    Next



End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    'This button closes the application and gives a message box.
    Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Thank you for your donation")
End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    'This button clears everything in the form.
    rad2.Checked = False
    rad5.Checked = False
    rad10.Checked = False
    lstNumberOfDonations.Items.Clear()
    txtAddress.Clear()
    txtCity.Clear()
    txtName.Clear()
    txtState.Clear()
    txtZipCode.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub rad5_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rad5.CheckedChanged

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

In your function, given that only rad2 is checked, you are doing

```
(if rad2.Checked = True),
```

you are adding values to Entries then you are setting the field to False

```
rad2.Checked = False
```

so, in the subsequent loop, the program will just skip the if condition, so the value for Entries is always 1 from the first loop

Do you have any reason for doing

```
rad2.Checked = false
```

May be, you can move this outside the loop.